# R apply multiple functions when large number of categories/types are present using case_when (R vectorization)

Tags: r, vectorization, case-when

Suppose I have a dataset of the following form:

```
City=c(1,2,2,1)
Business=c(2,1,1,2)
ExpectedRevenue=c(35,20,15,19)
zz=data.frame(City,Business,ExpectedRevenue)
zz_new=do.call("rbind", replicate(zz, n=30, simplify = FALSE))
```

My actual dataset contains about 200K rows. Furthermore, it contains information for over 100 cities. 
Suppose, for each city (which I also call "Type"), I have the following functions which need to be applied:

```
#Writing the custom functions for the categories here

Type1=function(full_data,observation){
  NewSet=full_data[which(!full_data$City==observation$City),]
  BusinessMax = max(NewSet$ExpectedRevenue)+10*rnorm(1)
  return(BusinessMax)
}

Type2=function(full_data,observation){
  NewSet=full_data[which(!full_data$City==observation$City),]
  BusinessMax = max(NewSet$ExpectedRevenue)-100*rnorm(1)
  return(BusinessMax)
}
```

Once again the above two functions are extremely simply ones that I use for illustration. The idea here is that for each City (or "Type") I need to run a different function for each row in my dataset. In the above two functions, I used rnorm in order to check and make sure that we are drawing different values for each row.

Now for the entire dataset, I want to first divide the observation into its different City (or "Types"). I can do this using (zz_new[["City"]]==1) [also see below]. And then run the respective functions for each classes. However, when I run the code below, I get **-Inf**.

Can someone help me understand why this is happening?

For the example data, I would expect to obtain 20 plus 10 times some random value (for Type =1) and 35 minus 100 times some random value (for Type=2). The values should also be different for each row since I am drawing them from a random normal distribution.

```
library(dplyr) #I use dplyr here
zz_new[,"AdjustedRevenue"] = case_when(
  zz_new[["City"]]==1~Type1(full_data=zz_new,observation=zz_new[,]),
  zz_new[["City"]]==2~Type2(full_data=zz_new,observation=zz_new[,])
)
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you have 100 functions, or do you have some rule to base the 100 functions for? If the functions are generalizable (eg. for group `i` we want `rnorm(x, i)`) If it is somewhat generalizable, it is likely simpler to create a function and use the arguments to handle this. For example: `function(x){if(!is.factor(x))x <- as.factor(x);sims <- rnorm(length(x)); x <- as.integer(x); c(20, -35)[x] + c(10, 100)[x] * sims}` would use the order of the `factor` to obtain the result in your example (assuming order is correct). Ofcourse is x is numeric this could be simpler.

Comment: Unfortunately I have 100 different functions which need to be run multiple number of times (10-20K times). The short functions used here are for illustration purposes.

Comment: How are these stored? Some generalized name based on the value it should be applied to? (type1 -> city 1, type2 -> city 2, all the way to city N) or would it have to be typed manually?

Comment: The functions are all written manually for each type/city upto type/city N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take a look at your code.
I rewrite your code

```r
library(dplyr)
zz_new[,"AdjustedRevenue"] = case_when(
  zz_new[["City"]]==1~Type1(full_data=zz_new,observation=zz_new[,]),
  zz_new[["City"]]==2~Type2(full_data=zz_new,observation=zz_new[,])
)
```

to

```
zz_new %>%
  mutate(AdjustedRevenue = case_when(City == 1 ~ Type1(zz_new,zz_new),
                                     City == 2 ~ Type2(zz_new,zz_new)))
```

since you are using `dplyr` but don't use the powerful tools provided by this package.

Besides the usage of `mutate` one key change is that I replaced `zz_new[,]` with `zz_new`. Now we see that both arguments of your `Type`-functions are the same dataframe.

Next step: Take a look at your function

```r
Type1 <- function(full_data,observation){
  NewSet=full_data[which(!full_data$City==observation$City),]
  BusinessMax = max(NewSet$ExpectedRevenue)+10*rnorm(1)
  return(BusinessMax)
}
```

which is called by `Type1(zz_new,zz_new)`. So the definition of `NewSet` gives us

```r
NewSet=full_data[which(!full_data$City==observation$City),]

# replace the arguments
NewSet <- zz_new[which(!zz_new$City==zz_new$City),]
```

Thus `NewSet` is always a dataframe with zero rows. Applying `max` to an empty column of a data.frame yields `-Inf`.

Comment: That makes so more sense now. Just a clarifying question here. Is this because of the subset function in Type1 and Type2 or is this because I could not correctly call each row of the observation inside case_when? Thanks a lot. I essentially want to pass the whole dataset as the first argument and each row of the observation as the 2nd argument here.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. I bet there is an not to complex solution for your issue. :-)

Comment: The function should take the entire dataset as the first argument and an individual row as the 2nd argument. What the functions does here is that it takes the subset of the entire dataset where the City/Type is not the same as City/Type of the observation, takes the max of this subset and finally adds/subtracts some random number. Does this make sense? Once again these functions are just for illustration here. When I type in "Type1(zz_new,zz_new[1,])", I get the correct result (I verified this). In that case, it correctly subsets the data and then takes the maximum value.